# using idf with denominator+1 when all documents has the specific word

Tags: python, tf-idf

According to some references I see that most of the time 1 is added to the denominator of idf equation to avoid the log it becomes infinity if a word does not exist in any documents.

But what if a word exists in all documents? Then idf would be negative. How should we deal with this situation?

Comment: can you give a reference?

Answer (score 0):

If a word exists in every document from the corpus, then its "knowledge" value is very poor - because this word does not differentiate one document from the corpus.

Answer (score 0):

From sklearn `TfidfTransformer`;

```
# perform idf smoothing if required
df += int(self.smooth_idf)
n_samples += int(self.smooth_idf)
# log+1 instead of log makes sure terms with zero idf don't get
# suppressed entirely.
idf = np.log(n_samples / df) + 1
```

`df` and `n_samples` are increased by one if `smooth_idf` is `True`.

So, we add one to both divider and denominator or we don't change any of them
**Since we also increase the divider, we never get negative values.**

In this example, we add `+1` to the log. 
Because, after this step, the `idf` is converted to a sparse matrix, and sparse matrix omits zeros. So, we want to have a value other than `0` for each term.

More about smooth_idf from documentation;

```
smooth_idf : boolean, default=True
Smooth idf weights by adding one to document frequencies, as if an
extra document was seen containing every term in the collection
exactly once. Prevents zero divisions.
```